# Xcode: How do I change my project folders name, without having building problems?

Tags: xcode, compiler-construction, project, prefix

I would like to change the folder name where my Xcode project is in. But when I do that I can't build my project anymore. It shows me 2 errors that says:

Apple LLVM compiler 3.0 error
file "*project name*-Prefix.pch" has been modified since the precompiled header was built

Any way to solve this?

Comment: I am facing the same problem How did you fix it..

Answer (score 40):

Select `Product > Clean` from the Xcode menu.

Then try and build again by selecting `Product > Build`.

Your project should build without errors assuming that targets are correct.

Comment: Kind of a 'duh' solution to this. Thanks for the answer, worked perfectly. Should have known better.

Answer (score 1):

Either you have replaced the code to some another machine. Try to commit the explicitly included import in the .PCH file. Compile it once on that specific machine. Now un-comment the those import lines and then compile the code again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to build project from terminal then

execute "$ xcodebuild clean " before execute the build command.

This will resolve the issue.